# Copying git branch into new repository as master

Tags: git

I have a git repository called RepA. 'RepA' has 2 Branches 'Master' and 'RandomStuff'. I have another repository called 'RepB' that has has a git init done on it and that's it. How would I go about copying the 'RandomStuff' Branch into the 'RepB' Repository and have it acting as the Master of that Branch.

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Same way you put any files in a master branch: just have RepB set to the `master` branch, make sure RepA is set to the `RandomStuff` branch. Then use a file manager (or a tactical `cp`) to copy all the files (but *not* the `.git` directory!) from the RepA dir to the RepB dir. Then you add all those files, create a commit, and push them up:

```
$RepA> git checkout RandomStuff
```

and:

```
$RepB> git checkout master
```

and after copying the content from RepA to RepB:

```
$RepB> git add -A
$RepB> git commit -m "copy of RepA's RandomStuff branch"
$RepB> git push origin master
```

Comment: So just do a...

    git clone,
    cp 'Whatevs directory' (assuming linux),
    git commit,
    git push

I guess the one worrying thing about this is I don't want my git push to point to the old repository (It's set in the git files I believe). Would I just manually delete those hidden git files?

Comment: `git clone cp` is not a thing, so I have no idea what you're thinking of here, but I added the commands involved.

Comment: If you want to keep the history of the RandomStuff branch, this of course won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use stack that often so I am unsure how to use that formatting you are utilizing on the comment section. They were supposed to be separate commands :P

Comment: @dunni Naturally, but that was not in the original question.

Comment: @derpyderp https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help has all the delicious details =) (it's basically just common markdown)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans well, i find that `copying the 'RandomStuff' Branch into the 'RepB' Repository and have it acting as the Master of that Branch` implicitly saying he wants the whole history of the branch. But maybe derpyderp can clarify that.

Comment: Hey dunni, it's not the end of the world if I don't have the history for this repository as this is planned to be just a temp repository and will be merged back into repA at some stage.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in RepA/master,

```
git pull <repB> RandomStuff
```

(where `<repB>` is either a path or URL to your other repository) should merge `RandomStuff` into current (blank) `master`, preserving RepA history.

Comment: Hey Amadan, I'm a nub so bare with me. If I were to do a git commit / git push after I have pulled the files is there any risk that I would push the changes RepA?

Comment: No; RepA is not registered as a remote in RepB, nor vice versa; RepB will have no knowledge of RepA's existence, nor RepA of RepB's.